# I want to access a variable of a file of one folder to the file of another folder....how can i do that?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, linux

Eg. I have a file1.c in folder A and file2.c in folder B

I want to access variable 'i' of file1.c into file2.c
how can I do that ??

Comment: Which language? Also, the directory structure has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variable in the file2.c variable by doing an extern declaration of it in the file2.c

For example if the variable i is defined as follows in file1.c

```
int i = 0;
```

You can access the variable in file2.c by declaring it as follows:

```
extern int i;
```

You can only do this if it is a global variable defined in file1.c